# ¿Cómo añado una información de la librería Pafy en un Label?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Buenos(as) días/tardes/noches tengo un problema en el cuál he intentado reparar pero no funciona ningún método, investigo y no aparece nada al respecto, comencé a crear una barra para poder escribir, creé una variable donde tiene una Stringvar() para que cuando una persona escriba en la barra todo lo escrito sea pasado al Stringvar(), por ahora el código va así:

```
>>#Creamos la variable enlaceu
>>enlaceu = StringVar()
>>#Asigno al Entry la variable    


>>browse=Entry(raiz,bg="white",width="50",bd="2",font=("Century"),textvariable=enlaceu)
>>browse.place(x=188,y=50)
>>#Luego de haber creado el bottom y haberle asignado una función proseguimos con la función.
>>def Enlace():
    1>>URL = Label(raiz,text="Probando URL "+enlaceu.get()).place(x=30,y=100)
    2>>video = pafy.new(enlaceu.get())
    3>>descripcion=Label(raiz,textvariable=video.likes,font=("Century")).place(x=200,y=200)
    4>>descripcion = print(video.likes)#funciona
```

Ya tengo todo asignado, todo funciona bien hasta el punto 3, al crear el label y asignar el textvariable como video.likes todo compila bien y sin errores pero cuando arranca el programa y procedo a poner la URL aparece esto: (¡Nada!)
[image: Se puede notar como un texto pero al final no pasa nada]

Como se ve solo se ve una "pequeña parte" del texto, he intentado cambiar las coordenadas y nada, si alguien sabe como repararlo sería de gran ayuda, ah sí, como vieron arriba hice un print con la misma variable y me imprimió el valor en la consola.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Soy novato en python y cada vez me esfuerzo más para mejorar, si tengo errores en el código me sería de gran ayuda que me ayudaran, ¡muchas gracias por crear esta comunidad!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JohanSDL26, bienvenido. Te cuento que tuve algunos problemas instalando Pafy, por lo que no pude probar tu ejemplo, pero de todos modos, te indico algunos comentarios sobre tu código.

1.- Tomando como ejemplo esta línea:

```
descripcion=Label(raiz,textvariable=video.likes,font=("Century")).place(x=200,y=200)
```

La configuración de posicionamiento de cada control, con tkinter al menos, es mejor hacerla por separado. Simplificando sería así:

> etiqueta = Label(raiz, text="hola")  # Retorna class 'tkinter.Label'

La cual es una clase con propiedades que puedes usar. Mientras que:

> etiqueta = Label(raiz, text="hola").place(x=0, y=0)  # Retorna class 'NoneType'

En este segundo caso, la variable tiene valor None, y poco podrás hacer con ella.

Resumiendo, tu variable **descripcion** tiene valor **None**, ya no tiene atributos de Label, pero de todos modos se "dibujó" en tu ventana.

2.- La propiedad **textvariable** de tu Label, normalmente se debería usar con una variable de tipo StringVar (refresca el valor en pantalla automáticamente), 
como lo hiciste con el Entry, sin embargo, tiene asignada **video.likes**.

3.- Lo que viene es un poco raro:

```
descripcion = print(video.likes)#funciona
```

A descripcion, que anteriormente quedó con valor None, le estás intentando asignar un **print**. Lo más probable es que el intérprete ignore la asignación (o de un error), 
y luego ejecute el print().

Ahora, lo que creo que tienes que hacer es cambiar esto:

```
descripcion=Label(raiz,textvariable=video.likes,font=("Century")).place(x=200,y=200)
```

por esto:

```
descripcion=Label(raiz,text=video.likes,font=("Century"))
descripcion.place(x=200,y=200)  # Sigue siendo de tipo Label
```

Y eliminar esto:

```
descripcion = print(video.likes)
```

Prúebalo y nos cuentas como te fue.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias por todo! También pensé lo mismo ayer cuando estaba razonanado, lo primero eso si no lo sabía, muchas gracias por explicarme y sí, funcionó, ¡estoy super encantado por ayuda! +1
PD: Me pasó lo mismo con Pafy, para instalarlo "bien" tienes que instalar el módulo llamado "youtube-dl".